# Check if field exists in DNS record using scapy

Tags: python, dns, scapy

I am parsing DNS packets using scapy.  Not all of the DNS Answer Records have all of the fields.  For example, some Answers don't have rdata so

```
answer = packet.an[0].rdata
```

results in the error:

```
AttributeError: rdata
```

Is there a way of testing to see if the rdata field exists in an answer record?  I know that you can check for layers

```
if packet.haslayer(DNS):
    <code>
```

so you don't ask for layers that don't exist.  Is there a parallel for fields within layers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could always do a try-except. Might not be as slick as what you're looking for, though.

```
try:
   answer = packet.an[0].rdata
except AttributeError:
   # do something
```